# Java Script convert string into multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am outputting from a PHP document my database query in a form of a string, something along the lines of;

ID-ImagePath-TitleOfPost-Text-UpVotes|ID-ImagePath-TitleOfPost-Text-UpVotes|ID-ImagePath-TitleOfPost-Text-UpVotes

I would like to organise this string into a JS array so that I can load the posts one by one. I have tried multiple methods but as yet unable to find a solution. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I have tried multiple methods but as yet unable to find a solution."* Such as?

Comment: .split('|') .. rest of it?

Comment: Please provide a sample of how the output (the multidimensional array) should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
var input = "ID-ImagePath-TitleOfPost-Text-UpVotes|ID-ImagePath-TitleOfPost-Text-UpVotes|ID-ImagePath-TitleOfPost-Text-UpVotes";

var output = input.split('|').map(function(x) { return x.split('-'); });

console.dir(output);
```

> I am outputting from a PHP document my database query in a form of a string

If you can affect the outputting string - don't output it like this!

Use `json_encode` in php and simply `JSON.parse` in javascript

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know about the json_encode. I will learn